# IllegalStateException: zip file closed

Tags: java, maven, tesseract

I have a Java desktop application that was running fine in Java 1.8; I'm upgrading to Java 1.11 for a client, and am getting the above error.

Full stacktrace:

```
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.init(Tesseract.java:442)
            at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:326)
            at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:309)
            at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:290)
            at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:274)
            at drivingrecordtool.file.DrivingRecordPDFTextReader.getOCRText(DrivingRecordPDFTextReader.java:152)
            at drivingrecordtool.file.DrivingRecordPDFTextReader.getText(DrivingRecordPDFTextReader.java:46)
            at drivingrecordtool.file.DrivingRecordFileReader.doInBackground(DrivingRecordFileReader.java:78)
            at drivingrecordtool.file.DrivingRecordFileReader.doInBackground(DrivingRecordFileReader.java:1)
            at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(SwingWorker.java:304)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
            at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(SwingWorker.java:343)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed
            at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.ensureOpen(ZipFile.java:913)
            at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry(ZipFile.java:348)
            at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$1.getEntry(ZipFile.java:1130)
            at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.getEntry0(JarFile.java:586)
            at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.getEntry(JarFile.java:516)
            at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getEntry(URLJarFile.java:131)
            at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.getJarEntry(JarFile.java:478)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:945)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:315)
            at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:455)
            at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452)
            at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
            at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
            at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
            at net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.LoadLibs.getTessAPIInstance(LoadLibs.java:83)
            at net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI.<clinit>(TessAPI.java:42)
            ... 15 more
```

The Tesseract library has a Java wrapper that I've used for months successfully but now seems involved in the error, whatever it is. I've been using the same DLL and started getting this failure, and I've updated the Tesseraact DLL and the wrapper to their latest version.

More puzzling is that the application runs fine within eclipse, and only fails like this when run from a command line (Windows 10). I have uninstalled and reinstalled the DLL a couple of times, rebooted the machine each time, and am running out of things to try. I went through the entire Maven dependencies list and deleted all files found there from my repository, then refreshed the eclipse project to reload all the files in the list.

I saw one suggestion of placing a breakpoint in ZipFile, but that won't help since the problem does not appear in eclipse.

I'm willing to upgrade the Java further, but it would be nice, first, to have some knowledge of what the problem is so that I have some confidence that will fix it.

Can someone suggest what might be wrong, or strategies to find out?

Comment: How are you running it at the command line?

Comment: "java -jar DrivingRecordTool.jar" -- it is built as a "Runnable Jar" in eclipse, with necessary dependent jars included.

Comment: Ok so it's definitely a fat jar? I wonder how it's finding the native libraries if it has them, which I think it does. Yes I know the exception doesn't talk about unfound libraries but... It would be worth double checking that the dependences are packaged exactly as they were in the java 8 version

Comment: I'm not sure how I would do that, and it seems highly unlikely to be a packaging problem. The wrapper is a JNA library, which I assume is calling the DLL I installed. But that's working in eclipse.

Comment: From which directory are you running it at the command line?

Comment: The directory containing the jar file.

Comment: Out of interest, what libraries are listed when you do ```dir "%TMP%\tess4j"``` ?

Comment: I'm in our chat window, can you join me there?

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248297/discussion-between-g00se-and-arcy